# Compare time difference

Tags: php, timestamp

I want to compare the time between sent messages, so that i know how quick someone would respond.

message_sent is the unix timestamp when a message has been sent. 
ID: 0000000005 is the start, ID: 0000000006 is a response on the message of ID: 0000000005.

With this data: 0000000006 sent a message on 1483021773. The original question was asked in 0000000005 on 1483021687. So the reaction time is 1483021773 - 1483021687. How should i approach this so i get an average response time?

The data
[image]

Comment: Do you want an average response time for the entire array of messages?

Comment: Not clear what your question is. It looks like you have all the data you need and know how to find the difference. Are you asking how to average numbers?

Comment: Please also clarify if we are sure the array of messages only contains conversation between user ID 6 and user ID 1.

Comment: @Pejman has a good point, and also, what if user 1 sends a message, then another before user 6 replies to the first one? How do you know which one 6 is replying to, to calculate the response time? Perhaps you should have a unique message or thread identifier.

Comment: @Pejman i want an average  response time for the entire array of messages. The messages contains only the coversation between user ID 6 and 1. What can happen is that user id 6 adds extra information to a message as you can see in the example, so basically he is responding to his or herself. That should not be counted in the average response time. I have to loop to the data and compare from_users_id. If the from_users_id is the same as your user_id then you should ignore an average time calculation because you are responding to yourself. I am kinda stuck there i don't know how to make the code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a response time is defined by the time it takes for a user to respond to the last message of another user:

```
$response_times = array(); // array of response times
// let's define a variable to keep track of the person
// to which another person will respond. initially, variable will hold
// the first message 
$initiator = array_shift($messages);
// now iterator through messages
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    // if this message belongs to the initiator, just update the timestamp
    if ($message['from_user_id'] == $initiator['from_user_id']) {
        $initiator['message_sent'] = $message['message_sent'];
        continue; // and go to the next message
    }
    // otherwise, calculate the time difference and put it in response times
    array_push($response_times, $message['message_sent'] - $initiator['message_sent']);
    // and update the initiator
    $initiator = $message;
}
// finally, calculate average of response time
$avg_response_time = array_sum($response_times) / count($response_times);
```

Comment: I edited my original post with a screenshot, is it clear now?

Comment: It is! Could you check the above code please? Given your data, it gives the correct average response time for me.

Comment: I am not sure because $initiator['from_user_id'] does not exists. Neither does: $initiator = $messages[0]; exists

Comment: Note that I assuming the name the array containing your data is `$messages`. Since your question did not indicate the name of the variable.

Comment: Yeah i know, but you need to compare with the next array and i don't think you are doing this right now

Comment: One thing, when i have a time send of 16:42 and a respond at 16:48 there is 6 min between (maybe some seconds too, but i dont mind that). When i convert that timestamp like this `date('h:i:s', $value)` i get the following result: 01:06:23. Why is it suddenly adding 1 hour to it?

Comment: Because `h` format character is a "12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros" (minimum value 01). You would want to use `H` and expect to see "00".

Comment: I actually used H, i made a typo, but both options are not working, i also tried G without leading zero but i always get this: 1:06:23

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know the exact code here is some sudo code with an example:

```
$total_items = count($array_of_items);
$starting_time_total = "0";

// Some code here to do your message_sent - message_sent = $some_value;
// Do the following for every single item for the $total_items in array
$starting_time_total = $starting_time_total + $some_value;

//Now to get the average we do this
$average =  $starting_time_total / $total_items;
```

So if you have 4 items in the array, with response times of 423, 395, 283, 583 respectively, you are left with an average response time of 421 which you can then convert to seconds of minutes or whatever.